# Reference to System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C# to command something in Excel but when I type

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

it's not recognized by Visual Studio
When I added the reference, I have this error message

> A reference to 'System_Windows_Forms' could not be added.
>   The ActiveX type library '...' was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.
>   Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: You should not be typing this by hand usually, if your project is a winforms project then the correct references are added by default in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you try to add it from the COM-tab? Find the System.Windows.Forms.dll in the .NET-tab instead! (Sorting the dll-s by name makes it so much easier to find the right one.)

Answer (score 0):

Reference Manager>Assemblies>Framework
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where is the "Reference Manager"?