# Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library

Tags: dll, f#

I reference:

```
open FSharp.Charting
open System.Drawing
```

In my project, I added to the references `System.Drawing.dll` which is the only one that comes as ".dll" - weird.

I get the following error message:

> Warning   6   Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library
>   "System.Drawing.dll". Type library 'System_Drawing' was exported from
>   a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.

What is going on?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve: just use `FSharp.Charting` from your `fsx` script, or build a WinForms or WPF application? This factor defines the type of needed project and required references.

Comment: I am building a console application, later on I plan to reorganize the work and restructure the code as a library. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what is specifically wrong with your setup unless getting full details required to reproduce the behavior. It would be easier to provide a minimal working sample that allow you get rolling. For directions upon using `FSharp.Charting` with WPF you may follow [library link](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Charting/blob/master/examples/UsingChartsInWPF.md). As it seems the [library](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Charting) does not give a WinForms advise here is a simple snippet for latest library (v0.87) and .Net 4.5. You define a `F# Console Application` project and add references to `System.Drawing.dll` and `System.Windows.Forms.dll`; assuming `FSharp.Charting.dll` is already referenced by `NuGet`:

```
open System
open FSharp.Charting
open FSharp.Charting.ChartTypes
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

[<STAThread; EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let myChart = [for x in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 6.0 -> sin x + cos (2.0 * x)]
                    |> Chart.Line

    let form = new Form(Visible = true, TopMost = true, Width = 700, Height = 500)
    form.Controls.Add(new ChartControl(myChart, Dock=DockStyle.Fill))
    do Application.Run(form) |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sidenote: one other error I made while trying to have your example running was that I referenced Windows.Forms via com rather than via .net (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858357/reference-to-system-windows-forms)